# Efficient way to search a vector of structs for a specific ID?

Tags: c++, search, vector

I have a vector of structs `Data` which has an integer data member `ID`. I need to search if it contains an instance of a specific ID. I had to do it this way:

```
int DataSize = 0;
for(unsigned count = 0; count < Data.size(); count++)
{
    if(ID == Data[count].ID)
        DataSize++;
}
```

Where `ID` is previously defined. Any more  efficient way to search a vector of objects ? Especially when it is a part of an embedded application.

Comment: You could sort the vector and do a binary search.

Comment: Is the record sorted by ID?

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can do a binary search.

Comment: No - unless you have the opportunity to sort (and use the sorted vector multiple times)

Comment: `int DataSize = std::count_if(Data.cbegin(), Data.cend(), [ID](const int& data_id) {return data_id == ID;});`

If you are using C++11. Replace `int` with the type of ID (I presumed `int`).

Comment: @gurka That's inefficient if it only needs to be verified there is at least one. Use find_if in that case.

Comment: @NeilKirk I just converted his code, which does indeed count the number of structs that has the id `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

```
std::count_if(Data.begin(), Data.end(), [&ID](const DataType& data){return ID == data.ID; };
```

where `DataType` is the type of elements contained in `Data`.

Note that there are no real efficiency gains to be had unless `Data` satisfied some more conditions, for example, being sorted by `ID`. However, using a standard algorithm improves readability.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 and lambdas could write a little more expresive as:

If you want to count the struct with ID:

```
std::count_if(std::cbegin(dataArray), std::cend(dataArray), [ID](const Data& data) {
    return data.ID == ID;
});
```

If you want to known if there is at least one:

```
bool found_ID = std::cend(dataArray) != std::find_if(std::cbegin(dataArray), std::cend(dataArray), [ID](const Data& data) {
    return data.ID == ID;
});
```

[The other algorithms of the STD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) it's always good to have at hand, some are used only very few time, but could save a lot of debugging (with edge case) and performance problems if implemented by hand.